# what does this ORM query means?

Tags: python, django

i understand the first query but what is second query is doing?

```
inner_qs = Blog.objects.filter(name__contains='Ch').values('name')
entries = Entry.objects.filter(blog__name__in=inner_qs)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is quite straightforward:

```
inner_qs = Blog.objects.filter(name__contains='Ch').values('name')
```

Search in the Blog table the list of names which contains ‘Ch’

```
entries = Entry.objects.filter(blog__name__in=inner_qs)
```

Search in the Entry table the list of entries which name is one of the previously found names.

Please, read the doc and play with the [Django tutorial](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/queries/).